# How can I serialize multiple executions of a stored procedure with the same arguments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a couple hundred line stored procedure that takes a single parameter (`@id`) and is heavily simplified to something like:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

INSERT INTO #new_result
EXEC pr_do_a_ton_of_calculations

DELETE FROM result WHERE id = @id

INSERT INTO result
SELECT * FROM #new_result
```

Multiple processes may invoke this procedure concurrently, with the same parameters. I'm experiencing that both executions delete the rows one after the other, and then try to insert the same data one after the other. The result is that one errors out, because it's inserting duplicate data and violating a unique constraint.

Ideally, I'd like to ensure that two connections executing the procedure with the same `@id` parameter will execute both the `DELETE` and `INSERT` serially, without locking the entire table. It's also fine if the two procedures are completely serialized, as long as they aren't preventing the execution of other invocations with a different parameter.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Is the proc inserting the same id it has deleted?

Comment: Quassnoi: The proc only inserts rows with the same `id` that was deleted, but to be clear, there are many rows with the same `id`. The `id` is actually a foreign key.

Comment: Any specific reason you're using `READ UNCOMMITTED`? Was it an attempt to handle this problem?

Comment: @Quassnoi: The procedure is very slow and has spikes of concurrent executions, but not for the same `@id`. Looking at history, it was added by a DBA to solve a major performance issue.

Comment: Usually (not always but usually) throwing a bunch of procs to SQL Server and hoping the locking mechanism would take care of everything does not work well and is extremely painful to debug. It's worth to spend some time and create a proper queueing mechanism. SQL Server supports them internally, see `CREATE QUEUE` and from there on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE  @lid INT

SELECT  @lid = id
FROM    result WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE   id = @id
```

and get rid of the `READ UNCOMMITTED` above.

Make sure your `id` is indexed. If it's a reference to another table where it is a `PRIMARY KEY`, use the lock on that table instead.

Better yet, use application locks ([sp_getapplock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Comment: Also, if *result* is clustered-indexed by `id`, then `PAGLOCK` only locks rows `WHERE id = @id`, and is way faster than `ROWLOCK`. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Diego: a page can share several values of `id` which will lead to the extra id being locked too.

Comment: `id` is nonclustered, and I can't safely remove the transaction isolation because there's a lot more going on in this proc (it's around 700 lines working with other tables). Is there any limitation on how many resources I can create with `sp_getapplock`? I'm going to have a number of unique IDs in the millions.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: no explicit limitations, the resources are just names you make up. Make sure to release them on time (better make them transaction scope)

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: note though that those resource names are getting hashed into 6-byte (I believe) identifiers compatible with the rest of SQL Server locking mechanism. Hash collisions are improbable but still possible.

Comment: @Quassnoi You are right, a page could have several `id` values. Note then that, if lock escalation is not disabled, your solution could also place locks on other values of `id`. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use application locks, for example:

```
DECLARE @ResourceName VARCHAR(200) = 'MyResource' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @id)
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = @ResourceName, @LockMode = 'Exclusive'

---- Do your thing ----

DECLARE @ResourceName VARCHAR(200) = 'MyResource' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @id)
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = @ResourceName, @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need these things to happen in a guaranteed order based on receipt of request, [Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) will manage that for you and throw in a bunch of other benefits, too. Setting it up takes some doing, but "[An Introduction to Asynchronous Processing with Service Broker](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/intro-to-service-broker)" by Jonathan Kehayias is the best intro I've found. You would set your "pr_do_a_ton_of_calculations" as the activation procedure for the queue and add the additional commands for handling Service Broker conversations.

This WILL make the stored procedures operate asynchronously from the caller, so if the call is being made from another stored procedure, the processing would happen off of that thread. This can actually be to your advantage if waiting for this processing is slowing things down.

Answer (score 0):

This may be just getting rid of the error and not fixing the problem, but

```
INSERT INTO result
SELECT * 
  FROM #new_result 
  left join result 
    on #new_result.PK = result.PK  
 where result.PK is null
```

Even without concurrency issues you would probably be better off breaking that up into delete, update, insert as an update is more efficient than a delete and insert and does not fragment index as much

```
delete d
  from result d
  left join #new_result 
    on #new_result.PK = d.PK  
 where #new_result.PK is null 
   and d.ID = @ID;

update result
SELECT result.colx = #new_result.colx, result.coly = #new_result.coly
  FROM #new_result 
  join result 
    on #new_result.PK = result.PK  

INSERT INTO result
SELECT * 
  FROM #new_result 
  left join result 
    on #new_result.PK = result.PK  
 where result.PK is null
```